# How to use Jenkins to import code from TortoiseGit

Tags: git, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I want to build a autotest framework in Junit, and I looked for many data. But it doesn't help me enough. So, I need some advice to solve how to use Jenkins to import code from TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1):

i think your question is how to Check Out the Code From Git in Jenkins Job? and one more thing i want to clear you that tortoise git  is just client(GUI client) to do git operation in Windows. The is no connection between Jenkins and Tortoise git.
If your Question is how to Get the Source code from Git Version Control to Jenkins Here is the answer.

1.Install Git Plugin in Jenkins.
2.While you configuring your Job In Source Control management Select git
3.Provide your git Url(Credentials if you have any)
4. Select on which branch You need to Perform the Build.